# Android Google maps click on no Marker points

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-uiautomator

I am using UIAutomator to perform automated testing with marker click on map:

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
UiObject marker = device.findObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains("test marker title"));
marker.click();
```

However, now i want to click somewhere else on the map. I tried using :

```
onView(withContentDescription("Google Map")).perform(click());
```

but this in many cases results with clicking on some other marker on map. Is there a way i can click on a non-marker point?